# Исправить ошибки в коде

Tags: c#

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибки

Задание: Даны два числа. Определите цифры, которые входят как в первый так и второго числа.

Выдает ошибки:

1. Использование локальной переменной "d", которой не присвоено значение.
2. Левая часть выражения присваивания должна быть переменной, свойством или индексатором.

   ```
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           int a, k,b;
           String d;
           Console.WriteLine("Vvod a");
           a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
           Console.WriteLine("Vvod b");
           b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
           k = b;
           while(k>0)
           {
               if (k % 10 = d)
                   Console.WriteLine(d, ' ');
           }
           k= k / 10;
           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний

Answer (score 2):

В ошибке вам очень подробно все описали. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда вы пишите `String d;` вы *объявляете* переменную, но еще не говорите, что там есть(не присвоили значение). Т.е вы назвали имя человека, но человека с таким именем нет. Если вы позовете человека по имени, то никто не откликнется. Ибо вы объявили об и только.

В вашем коде есть другой случай(выше строчки 1) `int a,k,b;`

Тут вы тоже объявляете 3 переменных, но не присваиваете значение, но перед тем как использовать вы пишите эту строчку `a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`. В этой строчке вы присваиваете переменной `a` значение, которое получите справа от знака `=`(т.е из выражения).

После того, как это строчка сработает, в переменной `а` у вас уже наконец что-то есть. Т.е есть и имя и человек(по аналогии).

На строчке 2 вы пытаетесь **использовать** переменную `d` в условии. Заметьте, не присвоить ей значение, а уже использовать.

Происходит это некорректно.
Вместо 
if(k % 10 = d)
Надо
if(k % 10 == d)

В первом случае это оператор присваивания, во втором случае оператор сравнения(слева в списке найдете эти 2 оператора)
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/

Вот вам и ошибка. Вы объявили переменную, не присвоили ей значение и пытаетесь по имени получить значение. А значения то нет.

P.S. Есть еще вероятность, что вы перепутали `d` с `b` , но дальше в строчке `Console.WriteLine(d, ' ');` вам все равно нужна переменная `d`.

В строке 2, как написал @Igor вы пытаетесь число со строкой сравнить. Это выглядит нелогично. Вы же не можете сравнить цифру 1 и слово "чебурек"?

Получается вы задаете вопрос: а равна ли цифра 1 "чебуреку"?

Comment: равна ли цифра 1 "чебуреку" - вероятно, нет

Comment: @Igor вероятно.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (k % 10 = d)
```

Если тут должна быть операция сравнения, то это ==, а 'd' не присвоено никакого значения.

Comment: Не говоря уже о том, что сравниваются целое и строка.